# Rails Controller - format.png

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, download, format, png

Trying to get a controller block in rails to work.  When responding to a url I want to show the .png file associated with the model.

```
respond_to do |format|
format.html  { render :blank }
format.json { render json: @play }
format.png  do  
send_data data, :type => "image/png", :filename => 'screenshot.png'
end
```

Data is working fine and is a 200Kb file.  The issue is when I go to the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/plays/testing1.png
```

it brings me to a blank page (I created show.png.erb and have nothing in there).  Not sure how to get the png file to either be shown inline or downloadable.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is the name/url of the controller that has the respond_to lines?

Comment: Route: `play GET   /plays/:id(.:format)   plays#show~
Controller name is: PlaysController.  The name of the action is show --Is this what you needed?

Comment: Thanks for looking at it

Answer (score 0):

Try using Conent-Disposition, you can either set it to attachment or inline.

Comment: I've tried, `:send_data data, :type => "image/png", :filename => 'screenshot.png', :disposition => "attachment"` and `send_data data, :type => "image/png", :filename => 'screenshot.png', :disposition => "inline"` - No dice.

Comment: Could the blank show.png.erb page be the issue?  I see that it puts in a src tag = `<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://localhost:8080/plays/testing1.png">` but when it renders the page the img is broken

Comment: Oops forgot to add your name on the prior comment: @alex

Comment: @AdamPerkins Where is this tag coming from? The page source?

Comment: That tag is coming from the show.png.erb page source after the call to the url is made.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but i've been struggling with the same problem for a few hours so in-case anyone finds this in the future:

I was also getting the same problem where a document was being generated in Chrome with a broken image and tag i.e. `<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://localhost:3000/open/28">`.  Also in Firefox I was getting an error saying there was a problem with the image.

The solution: I changed `send_data` to `send_file` which gave me the following code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.png {  send_file img ,type: "image/png", disposition: 'inline' }
end
```

[More info about send_file here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file)

After that, the routes responded by serving the PNG images without the broken image tags.

Hope that helps someone out.